# How to test a Method with an action delegate

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following call:

```
public IEnumerable<uint> DeleteAppointment(uint appointmentId)
    {
        return _dataContextProvider.GetContextRW().Run(db => DeleteAppointmentById(db, appointmentId));
    }
```

I want to test the private DeleteAppointmentById method but it isn't called of course. How can I call it?

The Run method:

```
void Run(Action<TDataAdapter> action)
```

How can it be void but still return the integer of the private function? I think I dont understand actions...

Comment: Actions don't return a type, try use Func<T,U> which allows a return value

Comment: I don't think that this is the `Run` method you call on the return of `.GetcontextRW()` because indeed this would never return `IEnumerable<uint>` (but always `void`)

Comment: Thats what I thought but it actuali returns a value as long as I send an action parameter.. if I remove it it is void again... never seen this.. this code works I just have to test it somehow.. without changing it would be great..

Comment: opend a new one with more information:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691199/how-to-unittest-a-function-in-a-mocked-method