# How to UnitTest a Function in a mocked method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

How can I test the DeleteAppointmentById here?

```
 Func<IDataAdapterRW, IEnumerable<uint>> function = db =>   DeleteAppointmentById(db, appointmentId);

 return _dataContextProvider.GetContextRW().Run(function);
```

_dataContextProvider is mocked with moq. If I run the test it never enters DeleteAppointmentById of course

The method to test:

```
public IEnumerable<uint> DeleteAppointment(uint appointmentId)
    {
        Func<IDataAdapterRW, IEnumerable<uint>> function = db => DeleteAppointmentById(db, appointmentId);
        return _dataContextProvider.GetContextRW().Run(function);
    }
```

DeleteAppointmentById is the inner method (private) I am really interested in.

my test:

```
[Test]
    public void DeleteAppointment_Valid_DeletedRecordId()
    {
        //Setup
        var dbContextMock = new Mock<IDataContextProvider>();
        var dataAdapterMock = new Mock<IDataContext<IDataAdapterRW>>();

        dbContextMock.Setup(d => d.GetContextRW())
            .Returns(dataAdapterMock.Object);

        dataAdapterMock.Setup(a => a.Run(It.IsAny<Action<IDataAdapterRW>>()));
        var calendarService = new CalendarService(dbContextMock.Object);

        //Run
        var result = calendarService.DeleteAppointment(1);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result);
    }
```

Comment: this is almost impossible to answer in this case, as all the important information is missing (what does your mocked `dataContextProvider` return for `GetContextRW()`? Is this mocked again? What do you expect? Should `DeleteAppointmentById` all some method or do you want to check behavir (as @Luke) tried to answer?

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve? From what you say is hard to make something.

Comment: Sorry I updated the question I hope it is more clear now.. There is a lot of logic packed in DeleteAppointmentById which has nothing to do with datacontext. I want to mock all data context and just test logic in that private method.

Comment: hmmm... did you not ask almost the same question a few days back? - yep only yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670372/how-to-test-a-method-with-an-action-delegate - I vote to close the question there as you provided more info here - but please don't post the same question multiple times - thanks

Comment: again: do you want to check that your `DeleteAppointmentById` calls some method on `IDataAdapterRW` or do you want to check the behavior? In the first case you just have to `Verify` if the right call was made on your `dataAdapterMock` - in the second case you should mock up a `IDataAdapterRW` in such a way that you can track insertion and removal of items and do what @Luke proposed below (but not on the real DB IMO)

Comment: I want to check behavior but I never go into the method on debugging because the mock uf .Run now just returns. I have no idea how to mock it that it still executes the function within. Is this even possible?

Comment: well you need another `var dbAdpMock = new Mock<IDataAdapterRW>()` and then do `dataAdapterMock.Setup(a => a.Run(..)).Callback(act => act(dbAdpMock.Object);` and then of course you need to check/verify/setup the methods of `dbAdpMock`... well the design is yours ;)

Comment: Ok I think we are getting close. I got a compiler error on the "act" delegate "Method delegate or event expected"Sorry Im a Lambda noob as it seams ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [access the result](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods) of the `Func` passed as parameter in `Run` method, and to *Assert* the result like below.

Why to return the result? Because it's a mock and *don't know how* `Run` method *is behaving*.

```
[Test]
public void DeleteAppointment_Valid_DeletedRecordId()
{
    //Setup
    var dbContextMock = new Mock<IDataContextProvider>();
    var dataAdapterMock = new Mock<IDataContext<IDataAdapterRW>>();

    dbContextMock.Setup(d => d.GetContextRW())
        .Returns(dataAdapterMock.Object);

    dataAdapterMock.Setup(a => a.Run(It.IsAny<Func<IDataAdapterRW, IEnumerable<uint>>>()))
                   .Returns((Func<IDataAdapterRW, IEnumerable<uint>> func) => { return func(dataAdapterMock.Object);}); // configure the mock to return the list
    var calendarService = new CalendarService(dbContextMock.Object);

    //Run
    int id = 1;
    var result = calendarService.DeleteAppointment(id);

    //Assert
    var isInList = result.Contains(id); // verify the result if contains the
    Assert.AreEqual(isInList, true);
}
```

Comment: this just tests it's own mocks ... I think the OP want's to test `DeleteAppointmentById` ... but if you add a few lines you can still manage ...

Comment: @CarstenKönig you were right, i modified the `Return` to give the result of the *parameter* passed in `Run` method.

Comment: ;) - ok but now you somehow have to tell the mocks that there *is* an entry with `id = 1` first and I guess that after the `DeleteAppointment` it should not be there anymore ;) ... you see this kind of tests are more brittle than the actual code - that's why I would never write something like this (not your fault) - but still you have to *Arrange* the facts first ;9

Comment: @CarstenKönig You are right, the actual `Test` is over `DeleteAppointmentById` method and we don't know the *body* of the method and `dataAdapterMock` may need some configurations, as you say, to return `id = 1`.

Comment: absolute genius you guys. Thanks that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests tend to take the following structure:

- Arrange: set up the context. In this case, you'd probably create an appointment and save it to the database.
- Act: call the unit you're testing. In this case, DeleteAppointmentById(db, appointment).
- Assert: check if side effects and returns were correct. In this case, you may attempt to load this appointment from the database, and assert that you were unable (because it should have been deleted).

Comment: **if** you choose to do it that way (although I would not call it *unit*-test in this case) than please make sure to clean up your *database* in a `finally` block - btw: I don't know how this answers the question at all but well seems someone does

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear enough, I know how to unit test but have a problem in this special case. I updated my description